# Ftp relative path in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp, relative-path

I have a problem that I don't know how to solve. Let me explain it...

Directory structure:

```
-/public_html/lab/
-/public_html/lab/upload.php
-/public_html/lab/plugins/
```

I am really newbie with php+ftp, but I have the idea that FTP does not use "absolute root path" (/home/user/public_html/), instead it use "absolute user path" according to the user in question (/public_html), right?

Well, in the `upload.php` I have the code where the FTP class take a file temporally stored at the same folder where upload.php reside (/public_html/lab/) and then try yo move it to `/public_html/lab/plugins/` folder.

FTP class receive a path where you want to move the file. But, I don't want to pass the path like absolute, I want to avoid this:

```
ftp->move('the-file.zip', '/public_html/lab/plugins/');
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
ftp->move('the-file.zip', '../plugins/');
```

But the code above looks like is not valid. So, how can I reproduce that result?

Comment: what library are you using to make the FTP connection? PHP's native FTP commands do not have a "move" method, AFAIK. http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Comment: Well, I'm using Codeigniter. But is it relevant the class/method to manage the path?

Comment: I was thinking you could change your directory first ftp->changedir per http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/class-CI_FTP.html but the more I look at it, is FTP really something you need? Why not just have upload.php move the file?

Comment: @zamnuts, PHP's native FTP could resolve it? 5 spended hours with no results. u.u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than FTP which is designed for communication between two different hosts, consider moving the file via [move_uploaded_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) in upload.php:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'],'./plugins/'.$_FILES['uploaded']['name']);
```

Once the file is uploaded via the PHP script, the temp file will be available in the [_FILES superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) under $_FILES[$inputFieldName]['tmp_name']. If you're using the example I gave, make sure to clean the "name" attribute before, since it will allow for client-side injection and leave a huge security hole in the application.

Comment: in retrospect i don't think this answer is helpful, but it does offer another perspective on file management.

Answer (score 3):

You can use php relative path Like for moving file to your FTP location

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/lab/plugins/" ;
```